# How do I fix problem with gui login not taking password and kicking me back to login screen?

Tags: video, xserver

How do I fix problem with gui login not taking password and kicking me back to login screen?

I can login at command prompt, but gui kicks me back to login screen.

I do not need to keep any configurations, .login , .bashrc or other profile information.

All I am wanting is a way to restore, install, fix the issue and not lose my /home dir files.

I believe the issue is some sort of xserver, video / display issue as it happened after I tried getting Google remote desktop installed and configured. That is an assumption at best.

The more specific question is what probably got corrupt? and if it happens again what components of Ubuntu probably need re-installed in a situation like this?

My assumption is that it is video/display related.

I was not sure what video card drivers my system was using and if that was the issue or if it was something only in some type of configuration file that got changed that might have caused the issue.

Comment: I can't mark duplicate question, but you can find your answer [here (ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).

Comment: Nhu, thank you for that link to article post. I think that is exactly what happened. I've since re-install Ubuntu but am saving that link for reference in case I ever have that happen again. Again, thanks so much.